# devise_inviteable - issue with GET users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=xxxx re-directed to sign_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

```
ruby '2.1.2'

rails (4.1.4)
devise (3.2.4)
devise_invitable (1.3.6)
```

routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users,  :controllers => { invitations: 'users/invitations' }
```

users/invitations_controller.rb

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # i dont need to override anything

end
```

rake routes

```
        accept_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/accept(.:format)         users/invitations#edit
        remove_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/remove(.:format)         users/invitations#destroy
        user_invitation        POST   /users/invitation(.:format)                users/invitations#create
        new_user_invitation    GET    /users/invitation/new(.:format)            users/invitations#new
                               PATCH  /users/invitation(.:format)                users/invitations#update
                               PUT    /users/invitation(.:format)                users/invitations#update
```

every part of the application needs to be authenticated -  except the **accept_user_invitation** path

my application controller does have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

Not sure why this is not working - anyone care to help me understand what I am doing incorrectly ? Every time I go to the URL I am redirected to signup

Thanks in advance. I am almost ready to roll my own !

Comment: how about change prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy] to skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!

Comment: @raykin, skip_before_filter is deprecated as of Rails v2.3.8 see here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/skip_before_filter. Using skip_filter still does not work. However, i am experimenting with the filters a little more - no success yet

Comment: apidock is wrong, skip_before_filter didn't deprecated, I use it in my rails 4.1.4 project, no deprecate warning at all. here is the doc in rails source https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/55cbb85fb7b7f4eaaa681e2a74cc8aca225097b7/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L99 . Actually in rails4, before_action is more suggested than before_filter

Comment: I check a few of the source code of  Devise::InvitationsController in https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb#L78 , I guess you code may be error in this method. You may either debug it by yourself or create an invitation by yourself, that should not take much time.

Comment: thanks for taking a look @raykin, you indirectly helped me resolve the issue by looking deeper into the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out why devise_invitable was re-directing and that was because the invitation_token was incorrect.

When overriding the default behaviour to send your own email

```
user = User.invite!(params) do |u|
  u.skip_invitation = true
  u.invitation_sent_at = Time.now
  u.invited_by_id = 1
  u.invited_by_type = 'User'
end
```

Looking at the code:
https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/lib/devise_invitable/model.rb#L200

There is a temporary raw_invitation_token which is the actual token needed for your url and invitation_token which is encrypted. I have to admit there was some confusion here!

In your url generation the token you must use is raw_invitation_token as devise_invitable will decrypt this token: https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/lib/devise_invitable/model.rb#L277

When I send the email or generate the link this works:

```
# use the raw_invitation_token rather than invition_token
# when generating your links for the mailer
token = user.raw_invitation_token

puts "#{accept_user_invitation_url(::ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options.merge({:invitation_token => token})) }"
```

Use the `user.raw_invitation_token` for your urls and the process works as intended

I have requested that the documents be improved and added a pull request - hope this helps someone

Comment: Hey, where are you putting that raw token code? In your mailer view?